# How to rename multiple images into two different names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rename, enumerate

I need to rename 992 image's name in the folder with Python. The name of the images should change based on their order. For example

```
current name
image_1 should rename to P1_ES_1
image_2 should rename to P1_ES_2
image_3 should rename to P1_ES_3
image_4 should rename to P1_ED_1
image_5 should rename to P1_ED_2
image_6 should rename to P1_ED_3
```

and again will repeat the same thing for the next six images just "P" will change such as follows:

```
image_7 should rename to P2_ES_1
image_8 should rename to P2_ES_2
image_9 should rename to P2_ES_3
image_10 should rename to P2_ED_1
image_11 should rename to P2_ED_2
image_12 should rename to P2_ED_3
```

the snippet I have already will change the names as attached file displays for the first six images which is not like what I need.[image]

here is snippet:

```
import os
import glob

path = 'F:/my_data/imagesResized/'

def rename_files(): 

 j = 1
 i = 1

 for i, filename in enumerate(glob.glob(path + '*.png')): 

    os.rename(filename[:], os.path.join(path, 'P' + str(i) + '_'+ "ES" + '_' + str(j) + '.png'))

    j += 1

if __name__ == '__main__': 

    rename_files()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `modulo` operator to cycle through your indices. You did the right job with `enumerate`. Another fun fact, use `sorted` to sort the images accordingly using `glob`, sometimes, the filenames come in random order:

```
fns = sorted(glob.glob(path + '*.png')): 

es_or_ed = 'ED'

for i, fn in enumerate(fns):
    # Check for ED or ES
    if i % 3 == 0 and es_or_ed == 'ES':
        es_or_ed = 'ED'

    elif i % 3 == 0 and es_or_ed == 'ED':
        es_or_ed = 'ES'

    # Create new filename
    new_fn = 'P{}_{}_{}.png'.format(i // 6 + 1, es_or_ed, i%3+1)

    # rename...
    os.rename(fn, os.path.join(path, new_fn))
```

For random images, that would give you

```
 old: image_1     new: P1_ES_1
 old: image_2     new: P1_ES_2
 old: image_3     new: P1_ES_3
 old: image_4     new: P1_ED_1
 old: image_5     new: P1_ED_2
 old: image_6     new: P1_ED_3
 old: image_7     new: P2_ES_1
 old: image_8     new: P2_ES_2
 old: image_9     new: P2_ES_3
 old: image_10    new: P2_ED_1
 ...
```

Comment: I have an issue that it always start with ED, but I need to start with ES. could you please point me to the right direction? I don't know how for you the new one start from ES. Also, I think something is wrong because the image_1 isn't correspond with the first image that renamed

Comment: Just change ```es_or_ed``` at the very beginning to ```es_or_ed = 'ES'``` that should work. If the first image is not the first renamed one, just check that everything is sorted correctly. Look first at your files with ```print(fns)``` using my above code to create the variable ```fns```.

Comment: sorting is sorted but still your script will start with ED while at the very beginning is es_or_ed = 'ES'. There is no luck.

Comment: I am not sure what is happening in your case, because I cannot reproduce this error. Look at the online Python tool, here it works as well. Maybe you can use [this to spot the error](https://repl.it/repls/UnfortunateMinorBinarytree).

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

```
def build_file_name(files): 
    p_order = 1
    current_e = "ES"
    current_e_order = 1

  for file_name in files:
    file_sections =  file_name.split('.')
    file_name = file_sections[0] #this holds file name without extension
    extension = file_sections[1] # this holds extension
    new_file_name = []
    file_order = int(file_name.split('_')[1].strip()) # Incause you're sure that it's always image_{some_number}

    current_e_order = current_e_order + 1

    new_file_name.append("P" + str(p_order))
    new_file_name.append("_")
    new_file_name.append(current_e)
    new_file_name.append("_")
    new_file_name.append(str(current_e_order))
    new_file_name.append(extension) #append extension back
    if file_order % 6 == 0:
        p_order = p_order + 1
    if file_order % 3 == 0:
        current_e = "ED" if current_e == "ES" else "ES"
        current_e_order = 1
    final_file_name = ''.join(new_file_name) # build normal path now.
```

Comment: thank you for sharing this. It cause an error  file_order = int(file_name.split('_')[1]) # Incause you're sure that it's always image_{some_number}

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'data/imagesResized\\image' could you please point me to the right direction?

Comment: you should first remove the file extension before processing it using the function I wrote, then append the extension once again. @Neda 
wait i will edit my answer to demonstrate this

Comment: @Neda check it out.

Comment: Thank you for edit the code. I am getting the same error. I just paste it on the question for now, and I will remove from there later. Could you please point me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Neda try adding .strip() inside the int() conversion, check my edited answer